# Issue with using Cloudera Connector for Teradata with Sqoop

Tags: teradata, cloudera, sqoop

We are developing a solution for moving hive tables to teradata and we are using **mapr-sqoop1.4.2** with **cloudera connector for teradata 1.0.5**. Mapr version is M5.
However the performance is fluctuating as some tables are getting exported from Hadoop to Teradata in 15-20 mins whereas others take 3-4 hours.
The no. of records and the file size is same for all the tables, as is the no. of unique values for the column that is used as the primary index in teradata.
(There is no skewing).

The question raised by the client is whether **cloudera connector 1.0.5** actually uses **FASTLOAD** or not. The data that has been transfered are showing up as
insert statements in DBQL table(Teradata) which does not seem to be using FASTLOAD.

So how can I be sure that the exports are actually using FASTLOAD ?

Answer (score 0):

The Cloudera connector is a wrapper for the "Teradata connector for Hadoop". Try using Teradata's connector directly to compare performance:

http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/teradata-connector-for-hadoop-now-available

Your Teradata DBA should be able to tell you from Teradata's Viewpoint tool's history whether or not FastLoad was used during the export.